# what does javax.validation.valid annotation on return type mean?

Tags: rest, web-services, annotations, endpoint, javax

recently I came across a method declaration in the following format:

```
@GET
@Path("/foo")
public @NotNull @Valid String foo()
{
    ...
}
```

I have problem understanding what the two annotation `@NotNull` and `@Valid` mean. Do they have the same effect if they were declared on top of the method declaration like this?

```
@GET
@Path("/foo")
@NotNull
@Valid
public String foo()
{
    ...
}
```

And it seems that if I have the `@Valid` annotation on, accessing other endpoints in the same class as foo will also trigger the execution of `foo()`.

Could some one share some opinions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do they have the same effect if they were declared on top of the method declaration like this?
**YES**

Accessing other endpoints should not execute foo() unless foo is called somewhere in your code.

@Valid annotation will execute validation on the return value.